# Where to store files for user in Android?

Tags: android, file, file-permissions

I have to export files from my application and looking for a solution, where I can save files, to give the user the possibility to open them.

I tried already getFilesDir().getPath() which worked well, until I realized that the folder can't open from a real device (/data/user/0/com.myapplication.example/files) since the /data path is just a storage area for the application.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Use getExternalFilesDir(null) instead.

Comment: Doesn‘t it require Permission? Is there an example how to get the permission? 

Comment: No permissions needed.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() returns a folder, which has user access right? That would be nice.

Comment: `until I realized that the folder can't open from a real device`. It is unclear what you mean by that. On a real device you can use that directory too.

Comment: if I use getFilesDir().getPath() it saves the files on /data/data/com.myapplication.test/files/. I can see this folder in the IDE for the Emulator. On my real device MediaPad M5 the files are stored in /data/0/com.myapplication.test/files/ <- This folder isn‘t accessible.

Comment: Yes your app does not need permissions  to write to getExternalFilesDir. I do not know what you mean by user access rights.

Comment: Sorry. Updated my comment, had press send before finishing my comment.

Comment: `This folder isn‘t accessible.` That folder is accessable by your app. You wrote a file in it!

Comment: Yes, it is accessible by the app, but from the file manager. I  have to give the user the ability, to open the files by themselves by using the native file manager on their device.

Comment: Which file manager are you talking about? How does the user open it? Every file manager will show getExternalFilesDir. Only a bad one on Android Q not. Which Android version in use?

Comment: Native File Manager from Huawei. Android Version is 9 (api28)

Comment: That will show it. Ir has to if it is a file manager. You looked at the wrong place. You know the value of getFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()? Have a look there.

Comment: If I was in the root section (/) no files or folder were shown. Trying to create the folder data in that section, shows an error, that the folder already exists. I think that is prove enough, that I was in the right folder and had no access...

Comment: No. From version 7+ root "/" is not accessable. No file manager can show it. But... Why are you talking about it? It has nothing to do with your post. Further i do not understand wich folder already exists and how that should prove anything.

Comment: I did a log.d to see what path the pdf file was saved in. Couldn't open this path though, since I had no access to /data <- to this folder, despite it existed. Now with getExternalFilesDir(null) I have another path => /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/
to which I have access through the file manager on my tablet.

So getExternalFilesDir(null) had helped me, to store the pdf in a path that can be opened by an user with the file manager. With my intention getFilesDir(), it was a folder, which was hidden from the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
I'm not sure what file type you are trying to store however what you have tried stores the file withing the applications directory and not the devices. To combat this I would look under either Media or Documents and other files again in the above link. I would be able to be of further assistance if I knew what file type you are trying to store. Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: Will look in this link later. The user should be able to take some pictures with the camera and the app creates an pdf, based on some data. So essentially, it should save pictures and a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to store a float array to the phone external storage. Pass the file name.extension in the String name. You could modify it to export your file.

```
public static void save(float[] input_array, String name)
{
    final String TAG2 = "->save()";

    String string_array = Arrays.toString(input_array);

    String fullName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SercanFolder/" + name;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SercanFolder";

    File folder = new File(path);
    if(!folder.exists())
    {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }

    BufferedWriter buf;

    try
    {
        buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fullName));
        buf.write(string_array,0,string_array.length());
        buf.close();
        Log.d(TAG+TAG2, "array saved as document. ");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG+TAG2, "problems while saving the file. ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion with getExternalStorage().getPath() (Thanks to blackapps) helped me to save the pdf in a folder, which can be opened in the file manager.